# Solana Devnet Transactions disappear

Tags: transactions, devnet, data

I have discovered that after some time (maybe a few months), some of my devnet data has disappeared.

I assume that this is on purpose? If so, is this documented somewhere publicly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, the transaction history for devnet and testnet is only backed by local ledger storage, whereas mainnet uploads all blocks to Google Bigtable.

It isn't explicitly mentioned, but https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-bigtable#solana-bigtable only talks about mainnet being backed by Bigtable.

You can also find the initial implementation proposal for longterm transaction history at https://docs.solana.com/implemented-proposals/rpc-transaction-history